# Is it possible to Filter / Seperate Data from MySQL in PHP from a rows content?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

What I am trying to achieve is a way to filter results from a table from the values in a a given row.

For Example: If I have a table for school times for multiple schools. I want to get all the data from the table and then have it separate into the schools.

So what would be the best way of doing this that on a webpage the data can be separated by headers for the different fields like separate the schools with header of the school names?

Comment: It would be good if we a bit of sample code of what you've tried.

Comment: Or an example of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: just track the current school, and output a new header when the school changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess first of all it would be good to extend your SQL query with the GROUP BY function or at least the ORDER function. After that you have to do a so called group change in your php code like in the following example code:

```
$school = '';
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // here 's the group change
    if ($school != $row['school_name'])) {
        $school = $row['school_name'];

        // header output
        echo $row['school_name'];
    }

    // output of the other data
    echo $row['blah'];
}
```